# How do I reference a value in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am accessing a record in a datatable with a row action and I want to extract the value of a field that has been specified elsewhere.

```
    const row = event.detail.row;
    console.log('row:', JSON.stringify(row));
```

The log shows:

```
{"Id":"000000000000000AAA","DeveloperName":"GWI_Default_App","Label":"GWI Default App","LogoUrl":null,"NamespacePrefix":null,"NavType":"Standard","UiType":"Lightning"}
```

I want to access the value of the DeveloperName field without having to hard code it like this:

```
const keyValue = row.DeveloperName;
```

I have keyfield defined already but I'm not sure of the correct syntax to use it to replace the hard coded statement.

```
 @api keyfield = 'DeveloperName';
```

Comment: Isnt row[1] returning developer name??

Comment: It may, but that is still hard coded and would have to change if keyfield changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
const row = JSON.parse(event.detail.row);
let val = row[this.keyfield];
```